# How to define the language generated by context-free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a context-free grammar defined:
**S -> aS,
S -> Sb,
S -> a**

I thouht that correct answer would be:
**L(G) = {aab}**, because:
**S -> aS -:> aSb -> aab**
but isn't.
Why, and what is correct answer?

Comment: What about going  $a\to aS\to aaS\to aaaS$ first? Maybe some more times... Then doing a lot of $S\to Sb$ on the result. Then finally removing the $S$ from the list to get a final word... Note that $a$ is also a word of the language. Please try more to have a more qualitative question...

Comment: ok, so far i understand, language is infinite because it can generate a lot of words
L(G) = (a^n+1 b^n : n >= 0), or something similar to this?

Comment: This looks better... Please adjust the question, as it is the guess is definitively false. It is a good idea to use mathjax, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, arrows can be better obtained using the latex `\to` for them. Also, is something like $a^5b^9$ in the language? Try to get closer to the right answer. (A proof would be induction, rather than inspection...)

Comment: I understand grammar can generate words that contain at least one "a", right? I just don't know how to write it correctly
$L(G) = (a^n b^k : n \gt 0, k  \ge 0)$

Comment: Yes, $L(G) = \{\ a^n b^k \ : \ n > 0, k  \ge 0\ \}$ is the language in a concrete writing! Well done! Welcome to MSE! Please edit the text of the OP to fit the new state of the art, and if there is still a question, write it. (It is clear that any word of the shape $a^nb^k$ with $n>0$ can be generated, e.g. via $$S\to Sb\to Sbb\to\dots\to Sb k\to \dots \to a^{n-1}Sb^k\to a^nb^k\ .$$ So one inclusion is clear. It is maybe less obvious to show that only such words are in $L(G)$, the other inclusion. Depending on religion, maths or informatics, one may need or not a proof...)